# Why does BitmapFactory scale down my image by a factor of 1.333 instead of 2?

Tags: android, image, android-resources, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have a PNG image file with 2236x971px dimensions as a resource.
I want to scale it down by a factor of two (to its half). However, when i use this code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bo.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image, bo);
```

the `decodedBitmap.getWidth()` and `decodedBitmap.getHeight()` show width: 1677, height:728 → Only 25% reduction in size instead of expected 50%. Why is that so?

I am running the code on API 19.

Comment: I suspect it's the "as a resource" part, particularly if the image is not in a resource directory that matches the screen density.

Comment: Did you call decodeResource before that with inJustDecodeBounds = true ? Try calling it before you set the inSampleSize to check the width and height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that, your resource gets loaded according to your screen metrics. Put your image in the `drawable-nodpi` Folder or open an input stream to your resource and decode that input stream.